# How do you get 'append' to active class-specific element? And remove?

Tags: jquery, html, class, append, addition

I. .slide-one.animate-in ---> add append

II. .slide-one ---> remove append

HTML:

```
<ul class="animation-canvas">
  <li class="slide-one">slide-one</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

HTML-active:

```
<ul class="animation-canvas">
      <li class="slide-one animate-in">slide-one</li>
      </ul>
    <div>
```

JS:

```
$('ul.animation-canvas li.animation-in').append('<div class="iebox">test</div>');
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/TP53Y/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you don't have a `li.animation-in` in your `html`...

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZrCvA/1/ ?

Comment: @Phil nor a `li.animiation-in`.

Comment: add iebox to every element in the original markup, and hide / show it on hover, don't add and remove DOM elements on mouse interaction unless you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Do it here

```
function () {
    $('.slide-one').addClass("animiation-in").append('<div class="iebox">test</div>');
  }
```

**Edit**

This might help you.

```
$(".addactive").hover(function () {
    $('ul.animation-canvas').find('.slide-one').addClass("animation-in").append('<div class="iebox">test</div>');
}, function () {
    $that = $('ul.animation-canvas');
    $that.find('li.animation-in .iebox').remove();
    $that.find('.slide-one').removeClass("animation-in");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this append to the `li`? How do you know what the OP wants?

Comment: @Phil If i understand correctly the div is added to all the li with class slide-one. But the 'animiation-in' also added like this. :-)

Comment: How to remove append?

Comment: @developingidea Do u want to revert the ul as it is when mouseout?